# Adding text into a static list in a global class

Tags: list, static, c++-cli, global

I'm using a global class for setting some information in it. I want to fill a list within this class.

I'm trying this:

```
#pragma once
#include "Element.h"
#include "PLCconnection.h"

ref class ManagedGlobals {
public:
    static List<Element^>^ G_elementList;   //wordt gedefineerd in ReadPlotFile.cpp
    static System::String^ G_plotFileName;  //wordt gedefineerd in PlotFileForm.h
    static System::String^ G_Language;      //wordt gedefineerd in MainForm.h

    static PLCconnection^ G_PLCverbinding = gcnew PLCconnection();
    static bool G_plcOnline = G_PLCverbinding->ConnectToPLC();

    static List<System::String^>^ G_VariableList = gcnew List<System::String^>;
    //static List<System::String^>^ G_VariableList = gcnew List <System::String^>;
    G_VariableList = G_PLCverbinding->LeesTest2(); // this line gives the error   
};
```

the error I get: `this declaration has no storage class or type specifier`

How can I solve this? I use this list on multiple places in my project, so I need it to be global.

Answer (score 0):

You must declare the `G_VariableList` member in a single expression, as below:

```
static List<System::String^>^ G_VariableList = G_PLCverbinding->LeesTest2();
```

If `G_PLCverbinding` is only used to initialize the static members, I would personally use a [static constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ke3a209d.aspx#BKMK_Static_constructors) instead:

```
ref class ManagedGlobals {
    static ManagedGlobals()
    {
        PLCconnection^ plcVerbinding = gcnew PLCconnection();
        G_plcOnline = plcVerbinding->ConnectToPLC();
        G_VariableList = plcVerbinding->LeesTest2();
    }
public:
    static bool G_plcOnline;
    static List<System::String^>^ G_VariableList;
};
```

Remember that any exception thrown from within a static constructor, or as part of the "inline" static initialization as in the first example, will result in your type being unusable, so you'd better make sure the methods from the `PLCconnection` class that you are calling to initialize your static variables do not throw. From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/k9x6w0hc.aspx):

> If a static constructor throws an exception, the runtime will not invoke it a second time, and the type will remain uninitialized for the lifetime of the application domain in which your program is running.

Lastly, consider that static shared data is a fertile source of thread-safety issues, so if you are going to read from and write to your static variables from different threads, you have to synchronize the read/write operations using locks or other synchronization mechanisms.